# Loading a shared native library in Tomcat on Ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat, shared-libraries

How do I load a shared library in Tomcat6, on Ubuntu?

I have created a library "awragrids" with name "libawragrids.so" and placed it in

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/shared
```

I have set the following environment variables in the terminal from which I call start tomcat:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/tomcat6/shared
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/var/lib/tomcat6/shared"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/tomcat6/shared
```

I then try and load the library with

```
private static final String GRIDTOOL_LIBRARY_NAME = "awratools";

static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary(GRIDTOOL_LIBRARY_NAME);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("Not allowed to load dynamic library " + GRIDTOOL_LIBRARY_NAME + ".");
        throw e;
    } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load dynamic library " + GRIDTOOL_LIBRARY_NAME + ".");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and wind up in the second catch block. All the reading I've done suggests that either of the first two exports should do the trick. On windows, I put "awragrids.dll" in a folder on the path and it works fine.

I have spent **way** too much time on this and really need to get some sleep... please help!

Comment: Does the shared library depend on some other library under Linux that it doesn't need under Windows?

Comment: are you running tomcat through a bash/init script? may not run as the same user

Comment: guido - I changed to root to run the script (I was using sudo, but thought that environment variables may then not be available... which I think is what your suggesting?)

Comment: David - I link to the same libraries... I'm not sure. I ran ldd against the library and found one library (linux-vdso.so.1) that I cannot find (find / -name "linux-vdso.so.1") on my system... perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: ... Well, now I understand why I can't find that one.

Comment: Did the caught `UnsatisfiedLinkError` have any useful information in its message or stacktrace?

Comment: @David No, as usual, it did not (I find it to be one of the most uninteresting of exception classes).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Tomcat's startup script--`catalina.sh` in `/var/lib/tomcat6/bin`--is actually using the `JAVA_OPTS` from the environment. In the script on the system I'm looking at now, someone put in a complete definition without pulling in the environment setting.

Comment: It is a pretty fresh VM (in VirtualBox). Both /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh and /etc/init.d/tomcat6 just pass the values of JAVA_OPTS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have been a mistake on my part. When I originally compiled the library, it had a different name ("libawargrids.so"), so I renamed it with:

```
mv libawragrids.so libawratools.so
```

While the equivalent seems to work on Windows, perhaps it doesn't work on Linux. When I compiled it again using the name "awratools" (producing "libawratools.so), the problem went away.

While the problem is now fixed, if someone could confirm that the renaming is probably what caused it (and perhaps explain why), that would be appreciated.

Sorry for wasting peoples time but thanks for the help!

P.S. I have now placed the lines:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/var/lib/tomcat7/shared"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/tomcat7/shared
```

at the top of /etc/init.d/tomcat6, so it does not matter which user starts the service. Please let me know if this is, for some reason, bad.