# Java Servlets and Raspberry Pi IO

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, io, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to learn how to write simple servlets to use with a Raspberry Pi.
I want to control the board I/O via web.I'm using the Pi4J library which is a wrapper for the WiringPi C library.It works when I use it to blink a led locally so I assume that I'm doing something wrong coding my servlet.

This is the code I wrote:

```
package com.luca.servlet;

import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;

public class MyServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

  private GpioController gpio=GpioFactory.getInstance();
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput redLed=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_23,PinState.LOW);
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput greenLed=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_22,PinState.LOW);
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput blueLed=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_21,PinState.LOW);
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput[] pins=new GpioPinDigitalOutput[]{redLed,greenLed,blueLed};

  @Override
  public void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.io.PrintWriter print=response.getWriter();
    print.write("<body>"+ 
                   "<p> Choose a color! </p>"+
                   "<form action=\"first\" method=\"POST\">"+
                   "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"red\"/>"+
                   "</form>"+
                   "<form action=\"first\" method=\"POST\">"+
                   "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"green\"/>"+
                   "</form>"+
                   "<form action=\"first\" method=\"POST\">"+
                   "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"blue\"/>"+         
                   "</form>"+
                 "</body>"); 
  }

  public void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.io.PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    String act=request.getParameter("button"); 
    switch(act) {
      case "red":
        togglePin();
        redLed.high();
        pw.write("<p>the led is red!</p>");
        break;
      case "green":
        togglePin();
        greenLed.high();
        pw.write("<p>the led is green</p>");
        break;
      case "blue":
        togglePin();
        blueLed.high();
        pw.write("<p>the led is blue!</p>");
        break;
    }
  }

  private void togglePin() {
    for (GpioPinDigitalOutput pin : pins) 
      if (pin.isHigh()) pin.toggle();
  }
```

it compiles fine and I manually deploy it inside tomcat,with the deployment descriptor and all.
But when I connect it says to me that the resource is unavailable.
If I remove the GPIO related code it works fine.

Can someone please help me out? Google searching doesn't seem to help

Comment: Did you see the log when the tomcat is starting? Maybe there is some error on the startup...

Comment: *".It works when I use it to blink a led locally"* - what does that mean precisely? It works when you test the library from a client Java application (with a public static void main()) ?

Comment: This sounds to me like you are not loading the library that the GPIO code lives in. This link frefers to Ubuntu, but it may point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773390/loading-a-shared-native-library-in-in-tomcat-on-ubuntu. Posting the output from catalina.log would help us diagnose this.

Comment: @DaveH yes,that nailed it! I forgot to add the Pi4J jars in the lib folder.. how stupid :D !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an ***Url Pattern*** in order to access to your servlet methods like **POST** and **GET**.

For example use:

```
@WebServlet("/raspberryServelt")
public class MyServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
...
```

And then access to the servlet methods doing a **POST** or **GET** request...

For example doing a get to:

> localhost:8080/yourWebAppName/raspberryServelt

Will work...

Comment: if it works with the GPIO code removed, isn't it unlikely o be a mapping problem?

Comment: I map the servlet in the web.xml file. It's not a mapping issue

Answer (score 0):

You must put in your project the pi4j libraries in path WEB-INF/lib